# I need help creating a quiz in visual basic with labels

Tags: vb.net, label

I am trying to create this quiz and assign each correct answer a numerical value so they are each worth one point. At the bottom there will be a button to add up all of the correct answers and display it in a label which will be next to the button. There can only be one label selected at a time for each question and if they do not select the correct one they get 0 points, i am in my first semester of vb so all kinds of help will be greatly appreciated.

Also the quiz will consist of 12 questions and each question having 3 different answers, i have named the answer "lblanswer1" "lblanswer2" etc..

Comment: you could respond to the click event of the label or add a radiobutton next to each to catch their selection.  not clear what you have tried or what *specifically* you are stuck on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First define the data, if you want to be able to change the questions this can be done in code or in a configuration file that you read in. Otherwise it could be done directly in the form.

**Data**

To define the questions in code, a question can be encapsulated as a class with properties for the text and answers:

```
Class Question
    Property Text As String
    Property Answer1 As String
    Property Answer2 As String
    Property Answer3 As String
    Property CorrectAnswer As Int
End Class
```

Questions can then be constructed, e.g.

```
Dim question1 As New Question With
    {.Text = "What is the capital of the Australia?",
     .Answer1 = "Brisbane",
     .Answer2 = "Canberra",
     .Answer3 = "Syndney",
     .CorrectAnswer = 2
    }
```

A quiz can be constructed as an array of questions, e.g.:

```
Dim questions() As Question = 
    New Question() {
        question1,
        question2
    }
```

**Form**

The form can be constructed programmatically using the data, so that for each question there is a [group box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a [label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.aspx) is shown with the text and [radio buttons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the answer. Or alternatively you can manually create the form (however you will not be able to easily change the questions).

Each question can be displayed on a form with a label for the text and radio buttons for the possible answers. Assign a value to the [Tag property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the radio button with 1 for a correct answer and 0 otherwise.

To calculate the total, sum the Tag values of the [checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) radio buttons.